# Project with path '' could not be found in root project ''

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have just imported a project from eclipse. The project consists of an android library project linking to the main apk project.

Folder structure is simple I have

```
rootFolder    
1) carEgiriLibrary    
2) carEgiriPuneBangalore
```

I get this error when Gradle try's to sync.

> > Error:(5, 0) Project with path ':personal:mCruiseOn:carEgiriLibrary' could not be found in root project 'carEgiriPuneBangalore'.
> >     Open File

```
Gradle-wrapper.properties

   #Wed Apr 10 15:27:10 PDT 2013
   distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
   distributionPath=wrapper/dists
   zip
   StoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
   zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
   distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip
```

gradle.build

```
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile project(':personal:mCruiseOn:carEgiriLibrary')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    //compile project(':adt-bundle-linux-x86-20140702:sdk:extras:google:google_play_services:libproject:google-play-services_lib')
 }
```

**Edit, entire build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile project(':personal:mCruiseOn:carEgiriLibrary')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    //compile project(':adt-bundle-linux-x86-20140702:sdk:extras:google:google_play_services:libproject:google-play-services_lib')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 10
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

Comment: What are  you trying to do here? `include ':personal:mCruiseOn:carEgiriLibrary'` ? `inclde <project>` lines go into  settings.gradle usually, not build.gradle

Comment: Im a newbie to studio, in SO (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23640059/project-with-path-mypath-could-not-be-found-in-root-project-myproject)  recommended that I put in this line..I'll remove it

Comment: Now I get a different error 'Error:(5, 0) Project with path ':personal:mCruiseOn:carEgiriLibrary' could not be found in root project 'carEgiriPuneBangalore'.
<a href="openFile:/home/jsiddharth/development/workspace/mnoxfrontendandroid/carEgiriPuneBangalore/build.gradle">Open File</a>'

Comment: Do you have a settings.gradle file? If you read the answer in the question you linked carefully, the line needs to go in settings.gradle, not build.gradle

Comment: I dont have a settings.gradle file

Comment: Post your settings.gradle file.

Comment: Playing around with modules helped.. thanks

Comment: Post a answer so that I may upvote you

Answer (score 10):

First of all in your root project you should have a structure like this:

```
rootFolder    
|----carEgiriLibrary    
|------build.gradle
|----carEgiriPuneBangalore
|------build.gradle
|--settings.gradle
|--build.gradle
```

In `settings.gradle`:

```
include ':carEgiriLibrary' , ':carEgiriPuneBangalore'
```

Then in `carEgiriPuneBangalore/build.gradle` you have to change your file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
        compile project(':carEgiriLibrary')   //You have to use the same name used in settings.gradle
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23  //you need 23 since you are using the  gsm:8.4.0

   ...
}
```

Finally you have to put a `build.gradle` in carEgiriLibrary folder

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

  //...
```

Comment: I have this error now.. \Gradle 'carEgiriPuneBangalore' project refresh failed
Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found.

Comment: @Siddharth May be you should study a little the gradle syntax. These are standard plugin for android.

Answer (score 3):

In your project is missing settings.gradle,
create a file with that name or copy from another project and write inside your modules:

```
include 'desktop', 'android', 'core', 'etc...'
```

Answer (score 2):

open Project view in  Android Studio you will find settings.gradle open it and add your library in include

e.g
include ':app', ':Android-SDK-master', ':library', ':zxing-android', ':your library'

Answer (score 1):

replace the below line from your build.gradle

```
compile project(':adt-bundle-linux-x86-20140702:sdk:extras:google:google_play_services:libproject:google-play-services_lib')
```

with this

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
```

Let me know if you face the problem

Comment: same problem @ line 3 after this chnage too

Comment: can you post your whole gradle files (both app.gradle and projet.gradle)

Comment: I dont have both the files. I have just migrated from eclipse, never ran this project in studio. I'll paste the build.gradle

Comment: change this "compileSdkVersion 10" to 23 instead of 10.

Comment: remove this  "include ':personal:mCruiseOn:carEgiriLibrary'" as you have already added its depoendency.

Comment: question has been modified based on your suggestion

Comment: then right click on your project and add "carEgiriLibrary'" as module..
it will solve your problem.