# Not able to reference other modules inside gradle project in intelij

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

I have created a relatively new project with 4 modules inside one project (created with intelij). However, I have now got to the stage where I want to import one module (:domain) from another (app-updater). The issue I'm facing is when I do this from within intelij it gives me errors in the "Build: Sync" tab. This is strange since my module app-updater is able to reference to module domain when I add the line "compile project(':domain')" into build.gradle and when I remove the line I get issues with the class being missing so the build: sync seems to be working it's just running it from inside intelij seems to give an error saying "Project with path ':domain' could not be found in root project 'app-updater'." I have attached my gradle config below, hopefully I have given enough info but if not feel free to ask for more, thanks for any help.

Main project settings.gradle file

```
rootProject.name = 'rGuide'

include 'domain'
include 'service'
include 'app-updater'
include 'app-rest'
```

:domain build.gradle

```
group 'domain'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    // https://mvnrepository.com
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.0.1'
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype', name: 'jackson-datatype-jsr310', version: '2.9.9'
    compile group: 'commons-lang', name: 'commons-lang', version: '2.6'

    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}
```

app-updater build.gradle file

```
group 'app-updater'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    google()
    maven {
        url 'https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/'
    }
    maven {
        url 'https://repo.spring.io/milestone'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':domain')

    // https://mvnrepository.com
    compile group: 'net.ser1', name: 'gozirra-client', version: '0.4.1'

    compile group: 'io.netty', name: 'netty-all', version: '4.1.36.Final'
    compile group: 'io.projectreactor.netty', name: 'reactor-netty', version: '0.9.0.M2'

    compile group: 'org.springframework.integration', name: 'spring-integration-stomp', version: '5.1.6.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.integration', name: 'spring-integration-core', version: '5.1.6.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-context', version: '5.1.6.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-web', version: '5.1.6.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-websocket', version: '5.1.6.RELEASE'

    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-core', version: '2.9.9'

    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}
```

TLDR - Trying to import domain into app-updater within intelij, it "works fine" and seems to import domain however when I do this with the Build: sync tab in intelij it gives an error saying "Project with path ':domain' could not be found in root project 'app-updater'.". Thanks for any help!!
[image: Intelij image]

Comment: Remove the colons form the include lines in settings.gradle

Comment: I've done this but doesn't seem to have worked :(

Comment: It still says exactly the same error?

Comment: Yeah looks like it, I've attached a screenshot as well..

Comment: `Trying to import domain into app-updater within intelij, it "works fine" and seems to import domain` how do you import it exactly? Note that you should only open main build.gradle (settings.gradle) file into IDE project (e.g. from Gradle tool window or via File | New... | Project from Existing sources... action). If project is built by Gradle - it will also work fine in IDE. About the error: verify that the project structure is correct, check e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/29469090/2000323 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/35426634/2000323 for this error.