# Android DeskClock not compiling

Tags: android, clock, android-alarms

I am attempting to use Adnroids stock DeskClock app:https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/DeskClock/

However, after updating the `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}


apply plugin: "com.android.application"

android {
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile "AndroidManifest.xml"
            java.srcDir "src"
            res.srcDir "res"
            assets.srcDir "assets"
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    dependencies {
        compile (project(":android-opt-datetimepicker")) {
            exclude module: "support-v4"
        }
        compile project(":messageformat")
        compile project(":support-design")
        compile project(":support-v7-appcompat")
        compile project(":support-v7-gridlayout")
        compile project(":support-v7-recyclerview")
        compile project(":support-v13")
    }
}
```

the errors of project references continue with:

```
Error:(50, 0) Project with path ':android-opt-datetimepicker' could not be found in root project 'DeskClock'.
```

How can this be reconfigured to work?

Comment: [datetimepicker](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/datetimepicker/)

Comment: This thread might help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/29469090/2445061

Comment: Generally speaking, AOSP apps are not designed to be built as ordinary Android SDK apps. They are designed to be built as part of a full firmware build.

Comment: @CommonsWare, is there a way to allow for this to become a full app? Or perhaps a fully featured alarm app that I could use?

Comment: "is there a way to allow for this to become a full app?" -- a fair bit of work, finding all those unresolved items (library modules, references to non-SDK Java classes and resources, etc.).