# How to programmaticaly hide clock from status bar

Tags: android, kotlin, android-source

I want to hide clock (only clock) from status bar.

My expected result:

Before
[image: Before]

After
[image: After]

My prospective solutions:

1. I thought make a fork of [DeskClock](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/DeskClock/) - default clock on Android.
   But i research this case, and from this answer - [Android DeskClock not compiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36489609/android-deskclock-not-compiling), got "AOSP are designed to be built as part of a full firmware build."
2. Make own version of clock from another open source android clock app.
   But in this case i also don't know how to hide native clock from status bar.

Comment: "But in this case i also don't know how to hide native clock from status bar" -- that is not from an app. That is from the operating system. To remove it, you will need to create a fork of Android that does not show the time in the status bar, then package that fork into a custom ROM that can be installed on your desired device.

Comment: Like @CommonsWare mentioned it's not really possible. Just an idea of a dirty solution: You can make the status bar transparent and use an e.g. image or programmatically generated bitmap as statusbar background. Then you set the status bar text color to e.g. white. 1/8 of the image on the left site is also white but the other part is black. But some devices their clock on different sites so you have to program a configuration for every device.

Comment: Refer this link its have about power bar hiding
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8273186/android-show-hide-status-bar-power-bar