# Project with path ':projectA' could not be found in root project 'gradle-tutorial'

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I'm new to Gradle and am following this [Gradle tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/gradle/gradle_tasks.htm), and it gives the following example, which I copied/pasted in my ~/gradle-tutorial/build.gradle file

```
project(':projectA') {
   task hello
}
task hello

println tasks.getByPath('hello').path
println tasks.getByPath(':hello').path
println tasks.getByPath('projectA:hello').path
println tasks.getByPath(':projectA:hello').path
```

When I run

```
$ gradle -q hello
```

I get

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/myuser/gradle-tutorial/build.gradle' line: 1

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'gradle-tutorial'.
> Project with path ':projectA' could not be found in root project 'gradle-tutorial'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

I did create a ~/gradle-tutorial/projectA/build.gradle file, but still got the same error.

What am I missing?

Note I did find [Project with path ':mypath' could not be found in root project 'myproject'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23640059/project-with-path-mypath-could-not-be-found-in-root-project-myproject) but can't figure how to make that answer work for my simple one-file/one-directory case.

Comment: Do you have a settings.gradle file? If so, post its contents. If you don't, that's why you're getting this error, you need to add the subproject into the settings.gradle file.

Comment: @nickb, that was it. I created a settings.gradle file with "include ':projectA'" and it worked. So the tutorial page is missing this tid-bit. But what should be the contents of ~/gradle-tutorial/build.gradle and ~/gradle-tutorial/projectA/build.gradle? Currently the second build.gradle is just blank. It works but doesn't make sense.

Comment: The projectA/build.gradle can be empty, or you can move whats inside the `project(':projectA') { }` block to be inside that build.gradle and then delete it from the main one

Comment: @nickb, that's it thanks. If you formulate an answer based on our posts, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error indicates that your settings.gradle file is missing or invalid. Inside it, you need to put a reference to the directories of the subprojects that you want to include in your build, like so:

```
include 'projectA'
```

For the build.gradle file inside your projectA subdirectory, you don't need to have any content since your root build.gradle file is already adding tasks specifically for the subproject by including the `project(':projectA'){ }` block. If you'd like to move the contents of that block to your subproject's build.gradle, the functionality would be equivalent.