# Issue while importing .aar dependency for android in flutter plugin, Project with path ':sdk' could not be found in project ':plugin'

Tags: android, flutter, aar

I am using my own plugin `payment_module`into my Flutter application. For this plugin I need to use external SDK which is in .aar format.

When I sync the gradle it successfully syncs but while running the flutter application I get the following error.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '%Your_Path%/payment_module/android/build.gradle' line: 64

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':payment_module'.
> Project with path ':boltsdk' could not be found in project ':payment_module'.
```

As In new android Studio versions we cannot import the .aar as module directly I have followed the suggestion from https://stackoverflow.com/a/70074787/22637043.

[bolt sdk location Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Py3K4.png) `payment_module/android/boltsdk`

boltsdk gradle file

```
configurations.maybeCreate("default")

artifacts.add("default", file('boltsdk-release-3.0.86.aar'))
```

My build.gradle

```
dependencies {
   ..
   ..

   api project(path: ':boltsdk')

   /// I also tried implementation project(path: ':boltsdk')

   /// and also tried implementation files('boltsdk/boltsdk-release-3.0.86.aar')
   /// for this I get this error Error building Android library: Direct local .aar file dependencies are not supported

   ..
}
```

settings.gradle file

```
rootProject.name = 'payment_module'
include ':boltsdk'
```

for this I already tried multiple solutions from [Project with path ':mypath' could not be found in root project 'myproject'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23640059/project-with-path-mypath-could-not-be-found-in-root-project-myproject)

Comment: Since this is a Flutter project, can you share your pubspec.yaml file? How are you importing the plugin there?

Comment: @tomerpacific heres How I have added the plugin

```
  payment_module:
    git:
      url: git@github.com:GitUsername/eo-payment-module-flutter-.git
      path: payment_module
      ref: workplace
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following content to this file
payment_module/android/build.gradle

**Note that it is not in the example directory**

```
rootProject.allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        flatDir {
            dirs project(':payment_module').file("libs")
        }
    }
}
```

[Screenshot of my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2rVw.png)

Comment: Getting error while syncing gradle Project with path ':payment_module' could not be found in root project 'payment_module'

Comment: "Payment_Module" should be the designated appellation for the module of your plugin project, while "libs" denotes the repository wherein your AAR files are stored.

Comment: I have revised my response and appended a screenshot of the project for your reference.